# Add polyline to google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am trying to add a polyline to google maps, so that when the location is updated, there is a line between the points. I have the following code that gets the lat lng from the geolocation, send this to a database via ajax and then adds the data to the polyline. The polyline doesn't show and the error message I get in the console is:

InvalidValueError: not an Array
http://maps.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/22/2/intl/en_gb/main.js
Line 24

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
          // Initialize the Google Maps API v3
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker = null;

    function autoUpdate() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {  
        var newPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
                                              position.coords.longitude);

        if (marker) {
          // Marker already created - Move it
          marker.setPosition(newPoint);
        }
        else {
          // Marker does not exist - Create it
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: newPoint,
            map: map
          });
        }

        console.log(newPoint);

        longi = newPoint['K'];
        lati = newPoint['G'];

        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo WEB_URL; ?>includes/send-coords.php',

        data =  {
            'latitude': lati,
            'longitude' : longi
        };
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {

        });

            // Creates the polyline object
          var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            map: map,
            path: newPoint,
            strokeColor: '#0000FF',
            strokeOpacity: 0.7,
            strokeWeight: 1
          });

        // Center the map on the new position
        map.setCenter(newPoint);
      }); 

      // Call the autoUpdate() function every 5 seconds
      setTimeout(autoUpdate, 5000);
    }

autoUpdate();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `path` parameter is Type: `MVCArray<LatLng>|Array<LatLng|LatLngLiteral>`

See in [PolylineOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#PolylineOptions)

So, you need the save all the `newPoint` in array. And then use as path for the Polyline.

See the edited fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/647/

Answer (score 2):

1. **Do not** use the undocumented properties of the Google Maps Javascript API (`newPoint['K']`, `newPoint['G']`), they can (and do) change with every release of the API.
2. The error message is self explanatory. `newPoint` is not an array, the `path` option of a `google.maps.Polyline` should be an array.